# Change Array with Integers into Octal Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, octal

So if for example there was an array x = [34,10,60,5,3]
how do I convert this to an array that's in octal?

Comment: what do you mean by octal? convert to string in octal representation?

Comment: @MarianTheisen Sorry for not being more clear. I mean base 8.

Comment: that is clear, but "convert to octal" is not. the only thing you can do is, convert to an octal string representation (see answer below). you can not convert to "octal integers"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```js
x = [34,10,60,5,3]
res = x.map(item => parseInt(item.toString(8)));
console.log(res);
```